# Select from table created within the same statement

Tags: sql

Is it possible to create a temporary table within a select statement that does not use CREATE TABLE (and that will work on a read-only server). I need to find the fraction of two values a/b in a table for every row where a different value c is a 1. I can use a subquery to find every value of 'a' where c is 1, and another subquery to find every value of 'b' where c is 1, and then divide them, but I thought it would be faster to find every row where c is 1 and then find the 'a' and 'b' values from that smaller table.

Comment: You mean like `SELECT ... INTO #TempTableFROM RealTable WHERE ...`? Or `SELECT ... FROM (Select a, b FROM sometable WHERE ...) s`? It''s difficult to understand what you're asking. Can you [edit] to include the query you have now, with some sample data and the results you'd like to obtain from that data?

Comment: Don't start with the technique you expect to solve your problem. Describe your problem first. You probably don't need a temp table at all, just a simple query. And always declare your database version please. Is it MySQL or Postgres? Which version number? The solution will be different.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) I removed the extraneous database tags.  Add the tag for the database you are really using.